# show dialog on a linearlayout class

Tags: android, dialog, android-linearlayout

I am working on an android application. In my app I am using linearlayout class and I want to open a dialog on a button click.So I wrote my code like the following

```
public class LeftSlide extends LinearLayout {

private Context context;
Button clickMeBtn;

public LeftSlide(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public LeftSlide(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}
private void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_slide, null);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    addView(layout);

    clickMeBtn= (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.clickme);

    clickMeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showActionSheet();
        }
    });
```

The below is the code for dialog

```
public void showActionSheet() {
        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
        // final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(MyBizcard.this,
        // R.style.CustomTheme);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pending_dialog);
        myDialog.show();
        myDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
```

WHen I am executing the application I am getting the exception

: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

I know the error is because of the following line

```
final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

What  I have to use instead of context?
I have to finish it any way.Please help me friends

Comment: use context of undelaying activity instead

Comment: @ Techfist...How can I do that?..Can you please give code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
private Context context;

public LeftSlide(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
this.context = context;
}

public LeftSlide(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
this.context = context;
}
```

Change your code of constructor to this, and use come context for popping up dialog.

Comment: dude, tell me few things, the activity from where you callin, it is in paused or resume state? if you have passed and valid context it will execute, put out code part from where this method is being called.

Comment: slide_me = new SimpleSideDrawer(this); <com.lic.helper.LeftSlide
        android:id="@+id/cool"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </com.lic.helper.LeftSlide >
  slide_me.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.left_swipe);..The code I used in activity is this and in leftswipe.xml file I used